# AWS API Gateway simple http proxy Invalid endpoint address

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to use an AWS API gateway to configure simple http proxy, following the example from this page:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-http.html
The issue I'm running into is that it seems to work if my endpoint URL is another AWS API gateway, but I can't get it to work for any other URL.

I'm creating a proxy resource with resource path /{proxy+} and enabling API gateway CORS, then creating ANY method as HTTP Proxy and content handling passthrough (just like the petshop example in the above mentioned example). If I set my endpoint to be another AWS API gateway, it works.

However, if I set my endpoint to be a non-AWS URL I get back a 500 response and I see in my API gateway Cloudwatch log:

> Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid endpoint address

My endpoint is on my internal company network, but as a test I also tried proxying to an Internet address and this failed with the same error. (I should note that in both cases, I am trying to proxy to an https address, not just http.)
[image]
[image]

In order to rule out a network routing or firewall issue I logged into an AWS EC2 instance in our same region and tested access to the endpoint URL via curl, and this was successful.

Has anyone successfully used API gateway simple https proxy to anything other than another AWS API gateway?

Comment: This should work if the site is accessible from the Internet.  Try using my test site https://echo.sqlbot.net if you want. (It echoes back your request headers.) This machine is publicly accessible and is not inside AWS.

Comment: @mojoken, Hi, could you please confirm whether you deploy the API [1] after you change the endpoint URL to a public https endpoint? [1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-deploy-api-with-console.html#how-to-deploy-api-console

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot I tried invoking echo.sqlbot.net and it went through successfully. So this would seem to indicate I have a routing or firewall issue. I will investigate it further.

Comment: @DenisWeerasiri yes I re-deploy my API after every change, thanks.

Comment: @mojoken at least you have some confirmation, now, that your general approach is valid.  I'm unsure exactly what conditions can cause "invalid endpoint address," but it could be a DNS issue -- the IP address behind the hostname API Gateway is trying to access needs to be a public IP address.  If it's a private IP address, that could be the problem.

Comment: In my case, I was pointing the endpoint URL to an internal URL which was mapped under `R53 private hosted zone`, once I changed it to the one in public hosted zone, it worked. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was assuming that testing from an EC2 instance would verify that there was no routing or firewall or DNS issue. This was a bad assumption, as it turns out that an API gateway does not necessarily live in the same network or have the same access as an EC2 in the same region. Thanks to help from @Michael - sqlbot I was able to determine that this was in fact a network access issue, but it was not one that my DevOps team was able to resolve due to the API gateway not being in the right network.

Instead, the solution turned out to be that I had to write a small lambda function (fronted by an API gateway resource with lambda proxy integration), similar to how I have written other lambdas for the RESTful APIs in our application. From the lambda I have more flexibility in accessing internal resources, including the ability to configure VPCs, so I was able to use standard HTTP client APIs in the lambda to proxy the call to the back-end resource.

Comment: I am trying to achieve something similar but without writing a Lambda. Our AWS accounts are connected to the Corporate n/w using Direct Connect. The APIG endpoint I created is a Private end point using VPC Endopint for APIG. The VPCE is in private subnet and has security group that has the allowed ports open but I am still not able to connect. I've also tried to using Route 53 outbound resolvers to our company's internal DNS server, but that didn't work either.

Comment: @Annjawn I am not familiar enough with the technologies you're using to be able to meaningfully answer. The people who answered with comments under my original question might stand a much better chance at answering your question than I could. Consider asking your question under my question, as they are probably not monitoring this answer.

Comment: Sounds like an expensive solution.

Comment: I am facing the same situation as you @AnBisw, did you find a solution?  I'm trying to connect an ALB in a public subnet but from an private API Gateway hooked up to VPCE for internal use only.  Wondering if you were able to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it doesn't allow URI that is pointing to root resource "/".
For example it wont accept `https://api.herokuapp.com/{proxy}` but will accept `https://api.herokuapp.com/v1/{proxy}`